# Simple php request. Sending a request from first page to second without landing on the page

Tags: php

I would like for page one of my instagram site to load the photos store the photo ids etc, and when a user clicks on the like button, the like will be fired off to likes.php    which will send the like to instagram. example below:

```
<?php

require 'instagram.class.php';

$instagram = new Instagram(array(
  'apiKey'      => '******************',
  'apiSecret'   => '******************',
  'apiCallback' => 'http://****/****/index.php'
));

$token = // code that generates and properly stores token;
$instagram->setAccessToken($token);
$id =  $_GET['pic'];
$instagram->likeMedia($id);

if ($result->meta->code === 200) {
  echo 'Success! The image was added to your likes.';
} else {
  echo 'Something went wrong :(';
}


?>
```

and for examples sake lets say that the page sending the like for right now looks like:

```
 echo "<img src='like.jpg' class='like' onclick='SendID("4358734534_5435435")'>";
```

What should SendId  look like? or what would be good to look into to get this task done, I just you to be able to click the button created above and send the id of that photo to likes.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample:

```
echo "<img src='like.jpg' class='like' onclick='likePic(".$picId.",".$userId.")'>";
```

Using JQuery http://jquery.com/:

```
function likePic(picId, userId){

    $.get('path/to/like.php?picid=' + picId + '&userid=' + userId+ "&r=" + (new Date().getTime()), function(data) {
       if (data != "ok") {
         //maybe error handling, if like.php does not return "ok".
       }
    }
}
```

without jQuery (plain JavaScript)

```
function likePic(picId, userId){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", 'path/to/like.php?picid=' + picId + '&userid=' + userId+ "&r=" + (new Date().getTime()), true);
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
          if (xhr.responseText != "ok") {
             //maybe error handling, if like.php does not return "ok".
           }
        }
      }
    };
   xhr.send(null);
  }
```

the `"&r=" + (new Date().getTime())` of both examples is just to avoid Caching of the result by the webbrowser.

Comment: Thanks @dognose , I have a question if you look at my script its "echo"-ing the result. Should it be doing something else instead  because in the javascript function it seems to be expecting "200" where it sais  "if xhr.status === 200"  What information would my initiating browser actually receive from this transaction?

Comment: @ModS You can't echo the result, without refreshing the page, because the complete HTML-Page has already been build. What you can do is: define a "area", where you want the message to popup, like `<span id='messages'></span>` and then - when you handle the success - do `document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML = 'Success! The image was added to your likes.';`

Comment: I guess what im trying to ask is, once Likes.php gets the result of 200 , do i have to "return" 200  or something in order for the initiating page (the page with the like button) to get a response?

Comment: `200` is just a (meta-)Response from the browser, telling the XMLHTTPRequest, that the page call was successfull. You dont have to care about.

Comment: Likes.php is going to send out to instagram and get 200 back.  thats understood.  But will likes.php automatically pass this 200 back to the initiating page?

Comment: Unfortunately im not familar with the instagram API, so i can't tell. From what i see (in your code) it requires a Callback-Adress. Therefore i'd say: "no". When YOUR `like.php` has finished the Call to instagram, it has no clue about, if the like has worked. Therefore you can't Output an appropriate result to be send back to your JavaScript, that triggered the request.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35463/discussion-between-mods-and-dognose)

Answer (score 1):

*onclick* is a so-called "event handler".
Usually, they are written in JavaScript.

Your example is a JavaScript **function** called *SendID*.

Your mentioned page (likes.php) would have to be visited using Ajax.
One of the easiest ways to implement it, is using jQuery.

Read more about this in the references below.

References:

- [Understanding "event handlers" in JavaScript](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/event2.shtml)
- [jQuery.ajax() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)